# How to fix these shadows?

Tags: shadows

I modelled a cylindrical component which I should apply some round cavities on the side by using a boolean modifier, although I get these shadows, when I mode to Shade smooth:

[image]
[image]

How can I fix them?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. We cannot help fix these shading issues without more details of the mesh. Can you share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Hello, I shared the file...thank you for your support.

Comment: Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using boolean, in this case you should better use *LoopTools > Circle*:

Simplify the topology, select some faces:

[image]

Remove them, extrude inwards:

[image]

Enable the *LoopTools* addon and right click > *LoopTools > Circle* (you can make the circle stick to a duplicated cylinder with a *Shrinkwrap* modifier):

[image]

Extrude inwards, bevel the edge, move some vertices:

[image]